# Plugin to display weekly schedule that can be edited via admin panel

Tags: plugins, events

I am working on a simple wordpress site for a fitness club. They require a simple wordpress plugin that displays a static weekly schedule for their theater.

They need to be able to specify what plays on what day of the week and what time.

A full blown calender/event scheduler plugin is probably overkill for this as it just needs to display Day of Week, Event Title, Event time.

Any ideas on what plugin I can use for this?

Answer (score 1):

Cant get any simpler than this (and without using a plugin) [**Display Events**](http://www.problogdesign.com/wordpress/an-updated-wordpress-events-list/) should be easy to bend it to do what you want it to do